# How to us multiprocessing in functions, when second function uses value decalred in first function?

Tags: python, function, python-multiprocessing

I have several functions and I want to use multiprocessing to run them parallelly when every other function uses the output of the previous function.

I tried using multiprocessing.Pool() calling pool.map() for every function. It runs functions alternately, first func1(i) in a given range, after finishing it, it moves to func2(i). But I need to run func1(i) and func2(i) together for given i, and move forward for next i.

**Note: My actual functions take hours to run, so I need to use parallel processing, this code is just a made-up example**

```
import multiprocessing

core_num = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def func1(i):
    global a # declaring it globaly to us later in func2()
    a = i**2
    print("i={}\na={}\n".format(i,a))
    return a

def func2(i):
    global b # decalering it glabally to use it in next functions
    b = a*i
    print("i={}\nb={}\na={}\n".format(i,b,a))
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=core_num)
    pool.map(func1, range(3))
    pool.map(func2,range(3))
```

The output is

```
i=0
a=0

i=1
a=1

i=2
a=4

i=0
b=0
a=4

i=1
b=4
a=4

i=2
b=8
a=4
```

I want it to be

```
i=0
a=0
i=0
b=0
a=0

i=1
a=1
i=1
b=1
a=1

i=2
a=4
i=2
b=8
a=4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `func2` depends on the output of `func1`, you cannot run them in parallel for the same `i`. But you can run them in parallel *toghether*.

```
def worker(i):
   intermediate = func1(i)
   return func2(i, intermediate)


p = multiprocessing.Pool():
p.map(worker, range(3)
```